# I want to set Snackbar in java class without binding layout with that java class

Tags: android, android-snackbar

```
protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject jsonObject) {
    super.onPostExecute(jsonObject);
    progressbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    try
    {

        if (myOrderSeterGeterArrayList.size()==0)
        {
            Log.d("Test","No Order");
            Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.layout.dummy_snackbar),"No 
            Order Found",Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
        else
        {
            mMyOrderAdapter= new MyOrderAdapter(context, 
            myOrderSeterGeterArrayList);
            myOrderRecyclerView.setAdapter(mMyOrderAdapter);
            mMyOrderAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

     } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
     } 
  }
```

Above is the code snippet.Please help me i stuck around.How can i solve this problem.In the `Snackbar.make()` "`R.id.layout`" is not identified,also i try to add `R.id.layout` inside `findViewById()` that also create problem,please tell me how to write this method.

Comment: What error are you encountering? It seems there's no problem with your snackbar code.

Comment: Issue Solved, You can not findViewById  layout  you can try to root ViewGroup findViewById

Comment: W/System.err: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No suitable parent found from the given view. Please provide a valid view.
W/System.err:     at android.support.design.widget.Snackbar.make(Snackbar.java:137)

Comment: Can you share your xml layout as well?

Comment: i create one dummy layout and want to attach with that java class in that Snackbar.make() method.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
Snackbar mySnackbar = Snackbar.make(getWindow().getDecorView(),"Snackbar message", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
mySnackbar.show();
```